# google spreadsheet time spend concatenate

Tags: google-sheets, time, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, duration

I have a google spreadsheet that has a time calculation in it. The calculation gets the hours and minutes between two different time stamps. It can exceed 24 hours. The issue is when I want to concatenate the result with a different piece of text.

For example. The time is 51:55. When I concatenate it like

```
=CONCATENATE("The time spend will be";text(Input!E13;"hh:mm");
```

*It results in The time spend will be 03:55.*

I can not seem to find a way to exactly copy the text. If I just copy the text I get something like 2.1205154.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
="The time spend will be "&TEXT(Input!E13; "[hh]:mm")
```

Comment: I just added the [hh] around the hh and it worked. Don't realy understand why but it did.

Ok looked it up, the [hh] shows the hours exceeding the 24h mark.